# Squarespace | How to Remove footer COMPLETELY from Pacific Template?

Tags: html, css, templates, footer, squarespace

This has got to be the most resilient footer i've ever seen in my life. Please observe subject A:

URL: https://xavier-jackson-ovac.squarespace.com

Hello, this website that I'm working on, I'm trying to find a way to have the background of this page to stretch the entire window no matter how i resize it similar to a cover page but theres always that grey footer underneath it. I tried:

in Code Header injection

```html
  <style>#header {
   display: none !important;
   
   #preFooter {
   display: none !important;
   }
   #footer {
   display: none !important;
   }
   #page {
   width: 100% !important;
   min-height: 700px !important;
   padding:20px !important;
   margin: 0px !important;
   max-width: 100% !important;
   }</style>
```

In page settings

```html
  <style>
  #footer {
  display: none !important;
  }
  </style>
```

It gets rid of the footer content and the prefooter, but for the actual footer? Nothing worked....

How can I have it so the background stretches the entire window? I'm basically trying to make it look like a cover page but with html functionality so i can add things like javascript / jquery. I have a similar theme using this template but I just need to get rid of that pesky footer. Help?

Its the white block at the bottom of my current page. Please help me destroy it... http://prntscr.com/aaelvf

it's the grey block on the bottom the standard template. Please help me destroy it... http://prntscr.com/aaeo8m

All help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The footer IS hidden  (you've hid the hell out of that thing). What's left is just an empty html tag. You'll need to add some content to make the page wrap further, or set the height initially to be higher (which will at least give it a white background), ie.

```
#page {
  width: 100% !important;
  min-height: 1200px;
  padding: 20px !important;
  margin: 0px !important;
  max-width: 100% !important;
}
```

However, idk that you want to set the page to be 1200px by default. You might want to take a look at the image itself, and adjust the height that's being set by squarespace (806px).

`style="top: 0px; left: -135px; width: 1210px; height: 806px; position: relative;"`

Comment: Your answer gave me hope! I was finally able to look at it once more and you were right, that code did the trick! Thanks so much!

Comment: No problem - just keep an eye on that because it may affect your layout of other pages. You might want to style something a little more specific than the `#page` wrapper, because this will likely affect EVERY page on your site.